# How to run a fragment test that has a LiveData observer with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-testing, robolectric

How do you launch a fragment in the test scope that contains a LiveData observer with Robolectric.

My fragment is observing the liveData from the ViewModel. If I remove this section of code the test runs.

```
fun observerData() {

    viewModel.MyLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        ...
    })
}
```

The test uses a fragment scenario to start the fragment.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class) 
class MyFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
         val ViewModel: MyViewModel = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
         val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(
             factory = MainFragmentFactory(ViewModel),
             fragmentArgs = null,
             themeResId = R.style.Theme_MyTheme
         )
    }
}
```

the test returns the following errors.

```
java.lang.Exception: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.
```

I've tried setting the main looper to idol but still get the same error.